# Python Cairo. How to draw a line around arc?

Tags: python-3.x, cairo, pycairo

I want to draw a line around my arc but.. I can't. It doesn't fit.
It's my first day with cairo, so I don't know much. How do I do it right?

I'm drawing it on a drawing area of pyGTK+3 in linux.

//I want to fill and close_path for the other end as well but I've commented it out so that the problem is more easy to spot.

```
pos = pos
w = 10
rad = 70 - w/2
b_c = (34/255, 139/255, 34/255)
ctx.set_line_width(w)
ctx.set_source_rgb(b_c[0], b_c[1], b_c[2])

ctx.arc_negative(pos[0], pos[1], rad, 0, -pi/2)
ctx.arc_negative(pos[0], pos[1], rad, pi, pi/2)

#ctx.close_path()
ctx.stroke()
#ctx.stroke_preserve()
#ctx.fill()

ctx.set_line_width(3)
ctx.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)

ctx.arc_negative(pos[0], pos[1], rad +w/2 - 3/2, 0, -pi/2)
ctx.arc_negative(pos[0], pos[1], rad +w/2 - 3/2, pi, pi/2)
ctx.close_path()

ctx.stroke()

ctx.arc_negative(pos[0], pos[1], rad, 0, -pi/2)
ctx.arc_negative(pos[0], pos[1], rad, pi, pi/2)

ctx.close_path()

ctx.stroke()
draw_spikes(ctx, pos, rad + w/2)
```

[image]